# SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'SQL Instance' failed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, configuration

```
Event Number: 3351
Event Level: 1
Event Computer: 'Server Name' 
Event Description: SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'SQL Instance' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Login failed for user 'DomainName\ServerName$'.

Reference link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj551781(v=nav.70).aspx
```

From the reference link I understood I need to give permissions for the login failed user on config db but we have 5 servers in farm and the error is coming only for 2 servers. Also we use AD accounts not the server local account. My timer service runs with Farm account.

Why my server local account is trying to connect with Config DB?

I could able to see this error from two weeks, my farm is up and running as expected. How critical is this error? What would be the impact if not corrected?

Comment: It looks like ur domain account not local account, is it service account? What are the roles of the 2 servers where u seeing error? Wfe?

Comment: Those are Application servers, on which central admin is hosted and on other server search is hosted.

Correct! account starts with domain name has to be a domain account but i dont think we have such accounts, we never used them any where. DomainName\ServerName is the account format. so it was failing for both the servers DomainName\App1, DomainName\App2. I dont see it on WFE servers.

Comment: Under which account SharePoint timer service is running? local account or farm admin account on both servers?

Comment: Farm account on both the servers.

Comment: Today i got it for all the servers. So, should i add all the domain accounts for the DB permissions list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database login for ‘Sharepoint_Config’ on instance ‘SQLServer\SharePointInstance’ failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
Login failed for user ‘Domain\ComputerName$’.

I have seen this a couple of times and in both cases it was due to the MOM/SCOM Agent that has a SharePoint management pack installed, the agents Windows Service runs as ‘Local System’ and thus causes this. The agent tries to access some information from the Configuration database and when accessing the database as the SharePoint Server’s ‘Local System’ account, it gets access denied, this is as it should be, the local system account must never get access outside of the server and especially to the config database.

The workaround in the cases I have seen this so far, is to either kill the SCOM agent service, or set it to run as a dedicated service account. The later is the one that sound better to me, so I will try and add info on how exactly this is done in an update to this post later.
What probably should be done when installing the Management pack, and this my personal guess so far, is that the service account for the agent, should be given the Add-SPShellAdmin permission on the Config database. This is completely unconfirmed, but if any of you would confirm that this is required, please post me a note.

On a personal note, this error caused by the monitoring agent, has been the cause of a lot of comotion and has in the end had me spend hours of unnessesary hours on finding it and mitigating its effects and also calming down the operations people that think my farms have broken…
Note:
The required permissions for the configured run as account on an individual SharePoint farm are:
•Local admin on all SharePoint Front End and Application Servers
•Local admin on all SQL machines that host SharePoint databases
•Full Farm Administrator rights within SharePoint 2010
•DBO for all SharePoint databases
(From: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2690744)